# How to observe store collection

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have code for generate checkboxes list:

```
accountsCheckboxes: Ember.computed('accountsCheckboxes.@each', function(){
  return this.model.accounts.map(row => {
    return {
      label: row.get('name'),
      value: row.get('id')
    };
  })
}),
```

but after modify accounts collection, add or remove, this computed property doesnt refresh. I tried find how to do it with events, or how to observe store collection, but without success.
I modyfy this model collection in others controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a little confusing what you're trying to do by observing the same property you're defining:

```
// accountsCheckboxes observes accountsCheckboxes?
accountsCheckboxes: Ember.computed('accountsCheckboxes.@each', ...)
```

This won't work and will probably result in an infinite chain of lookups.

Did you mean to observe `model.accounts` instead? If so, this is what you could've done:

```
accountsCheckboxes: Ember.computed('model.accounts.@each.name', function() {
  return this.get('model.accounts').map(row => {
    return {
      label: row.get('name'),
      value: row.get('id')
    };
  })
});
```

Note that you must call `this.get('model')`, not `this.model` to make sure you always get the proper data.

Alternatively, you might use  [Ember.computed.map](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_map):

```
accountsCheckboxes: Ember.computed.map('model.accounts.@each.name', function(row) {
  return {
    label: row.get('name'),
    value: row.get('id')
  };
});
```

Comment: You don't need volatile for this

Comment: it looks like the op wants to recompute this prop depending on checkboxes, both `model.accounts.[]` and `accountsCheckboxes.@each.name` need to be dependent keys.

Comment: Sure but it doesn't make sense for a property to observe itself, how would you even define that, creating a property with the same name on an object, overrides the previous definition (or throws an error).

Comment: I completely missed that the property name is `accountsCheckboxes` x.x